# Finding Origin of Symbol Dependency

Tags: c++, linker

I am working on a fairly large project that has a ton of external dependencies. I have been working on debug build during development for a while. Now, when I try and build release (after a long time), I get an error saying that a particular symbol is not found. In my case specifically, the linker gives me an error saying `start_thread_noexcept` symbol is not found. This symbol is expected to be found in boost-thread but when I examine the version of boost-thread I have using `nm -G -D --demangle`, I find that indeed this symbol is not found (I do find a symbol named `start_thread` though). Apparently, the noexcept symbol can be found in more recent versions of the library.

My question however, is more generic. What I want to do now, is to find the origin of this symbol's requirement. I am guessing that there must be some new function call I am making which in turn invokes the `start_thread_noexcept` function. Clearly, there must be a `.o` file generated when compiling my code, that I can trace this requirement down to. Either that, or I have added some new third party dependency which in turn requires the new version of the boost-thread library. How can I find what code/library requires this undefined symbol?

Comment: You can start by enumerating your objects and external dependencies, and running `nm --demangle | grep mysterysymbol` on each one in turn.

Comment: The linker should also print the object file requesting the unresolved symbol (see e.g. [this nifty example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b36bba77ee83de65)). What is the linker error message?

Answer (score 2):

I went to the intermediate directory and did

```
for x in *.o; do echo $x; nm $x | grep "_ZN5boostlsIcSt11"; done
```

This allowed me to track down the compilation unit, which in turn allowed me to find (manually) the offending bit of code.

Comment: Also make sure that you also do this search in all directories where libraries for the build are located